# 2018 Macbook pro Crashing/restarting frequently, help!

Tags: macbook-pro, crash

My 2018 Macbook Pro (Monterey 12.6) keeps crashing/restarting. It seems to be related to sleeping or waking from sleep, and can also be triggered by plugging in or unplugging a 2nd monitor.

This is the crash log:

```
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff8008d7999f): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from WindowServer in 120 seconds service: logd, total successful checkins since wake (15670 seconds ago): 1568, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago service: WindowServer, total successful checkins since wake (15670 seconds ago): 1552, last successful checkin: 120 seconds ago service: remoted, total successful checkins since wake (15670 seconds ago): 1568, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago service: opendirectoryd, total successful checkins since wake (15670 seconds ago): 1568, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago

Panicked task 0xffffff8bafb1b000: 3 threads: pid 109: watchdogd Backtrace (CPU 4), panicked thread: 0xffffff954686e540, Frame : Return Address 0xfffffff56875b690 : 0xffffff800587fdad 0xfffffff56875b6e0 : 0xffffff80059e10d6 0xfffffff56875b720 : 0xffffff80059d0443 0xfffffff56875b770 : 0xffffff800581fa70 0xfffffff56875b790 : 0xffffff800588017d 0xfffffff56875b8b0 : 0xffffff800587f936 0xfffffff56875b910 : 0xffffff8006115153 0xfffffff56875ba00 : 0xffffff8008d7999f 0xfffffff56875ba10 : 0xffffff8008d795f2 0xfffffff56875ba30 : 0xffffff8008d78971 0xfffffff56875bb60 : 0xffffff80060838ec 0xfffffff56875bcc0 : 0xffffff8005986dd6 0xfffffff56875bdd0 : 0xffffff800585a9bb 0xfffffff56875be60 : 0xffffff80058711e9 0xfffffff56875bef0 : 0xffffff80059b30aa 0xfffffff56875bfa0 : 0xffffff8005820256 Kernel Extensions in backtrace: com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[72F13DD7-D531-351F-8628-18318F125B22]@0xffffff8008d77000->0xffffff8008d79fff

Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffff954686e540): watchdogd Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version: 21G115

Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Mon Aug 22 20:17:10 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.140.49~2/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel UUID: 06A10466-36D7-3A0B-9EE7-A9053A8991A3 KernelCache slide: 0x0000000005600000 KernelCache base: 0xffffff8005800000 Kernel slide: 0x0000000005610000 Kernel text base: 0xffffff8005810000 __HIB text base: 0xffffff8005700000 System model name: MacBookPro15,1 (Mac-937A206F2EE63C01) System shutdown begun: NO Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 73810638926670 Last Sleep: absolute base_tsc base_nano Uptime : 0x0000432160e9f6e1 Sleep : 0x000034e07d9b3718 0x00000000751f3ab9 0x000034d49e451c49 Wake : 0x000034e08c654525 0x0000000075b32f47 0x000034e087ae5cde Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space Zone info: Zone map: 0xffffff80797d1000 - 0xffffffa0797d1000 . PGZ : 0xffffff80797d1000 - 0xffffff807d7d2000 . VM : 0xffffff807d7d2000 - 0xffffff8549b05000 . RO : 0xffffff8549b05000 - 0xffffff86e316b000 . GEN0 : 0xffffff86e316b000 - 0xffffff8baf49e000 . GEN1 : 0xffffff8baf49e000 - 0xffffff907b7d1000 . GEN2 : 0xffffff907b7d1000 - 0xffffff9547b04000 . GEN3 : 0xffffff9547b04000 - 0xffffff9a13e37000 . DATA : 0xffffff9a13e37000 - 0xffffffa0797d1000 Metadata: 0xffffffa0be731000 - 0xffffffa0de731000 Bitmaps : 0xffffffa0de731000 - 0xffffffa0ea731000

last started kext at 20437300714800: >usb.cdc.acm 5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9e61d000, size 12288) last stopped kext at 73511084476975: @UVCService 1 (addr 0xffffff7f9eaf9000, size 4096) loaded kexts: com.shinywhitebox.iShowU-Audio-Capture 1.0.4 com.uaudio.driver.UAD2System 9.15.0 com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower 2 |SCSITaskUserClient 456.140.3 !APlatformEnabler 2.7.0d0 X86PlatformShim 1.0.0 AGPM 129 @filesystems.autofs 3.0 !AHIDALSService 1 !ATopCaseHIDEventDriver 5450.8 @kext.AMDFramebuffer 4.0.8 !AUpstreamUserClient 3.6.9 @kext.AMDRadeonX4000 4.0.8 @kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager 4.0.8 !AGFXHDA 140.3 !ABridgeAudio!C 240.6 !A!IKBLGraphics 18.0.8 !AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.5.7 BridgeAudioCommunication 240.6 !AAVEBridge 6.1 @AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics 6.5.7 @kext.AMD9500!C 4.0.8 pmtelemetry 1 |IOUserEthernet 1.0.1 usb.!UUserHCI 1 !AHV 1 !ADiskImages2 126.141.2 !AMuxControl2 6.5.7 AGDCBacklightControl 6.5.7 !A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1 !A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0 !AMCCSControl 1.16 !A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 18.0.8 !AThunderboltIP 4.0.3 usb.!UHostBillboardDevice 1.0 BCMWLANFirmware4387.Hashstore 1 BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore 1 BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore 1 BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore 1 BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore 1 !AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1 @filesystems.tmpfs 1 @filesystems.lifs 1 @filesystems.hfs.kext 583.100.10 @BootCache 40 @!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0 @!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1 @filesystems.apfs 1934.141.2 !ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac 1 @private.KextAudit 1.0 !ASmartBatteryManager 161.0.0 !AACPIButtons 6.1 !ASMBIOS 2.1 !AACPIEC 6.1 !AAPIC 1.7 @!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0 @nke.applicationfirewall 402 |IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1 |EndpointSecurity 1 @Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0 @kec.!AEncryptedArchive 1 !UMergeNub 900.4.2 driverkit.serial 6.0.0 @kext.triggers 1.0 !AHIDKeyboard 228.2 !AActuatorDriver 5460.1 !AMultitouchDriver 5460.1 !AInputDeviceSupport 5460.1 !AHS!BDriver 5450.8 IO!BHIDDriver 9.0.0 @kext.AMDRadeonX4100HWLibs 1.0 @kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices 4.0.8 !A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60 !A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60 !AOnboardSerial 1.0 !UAudio 416.2 !AAudioClockLibs 140.1 @kext.AMDSupport 4.0.8 |IOAudio!F 340.2 @vecLib.kext 1.2.0 |IO!BSerialManager 9.0.0 |IO!BPacketLogger 9.0.0 |IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 9.0.0 |IO!BHost!CUARTTransport 9.0.0 |IO!BHost!CTransport 9.0.0 IO!BHost!CPCIeTransport 9.0.0 |IOAVB!F 1040.6 @plugin.IOgPTPPlugin 1040.3 |IOEthernetAVB!C 1.1.0 |CSR!BHost!CUSBTransport 9.0.0 |Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport 9.0.0 |Broadcom!B20703USBTransport 9.0.0 !AIPAppender 1.0 !AGraphicsControl 6.5.7 X86PlatformPlugin 1.0.0 IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8 @!AGPUWrangler 6.5.7 |IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F 1.0.0 !ABacklightExpert 1.1.0 |IONDRVSupport 597 !ASMBus!C 1.0.18d1 |IOAccelerator!F2 462.8 @!AGraphicsDeviceControl 6.5.7 |IOGraphics!F 597 !AThunderboltDPOutAdapter 8.5.1 usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2 usb.cdc.ecm 5.0.0 usb.cdc.ncm 5.0.0 usb.cdc 5.0.0 usb.networking 5.0.0 usb.!UHostCompositeDevice 1.2 !AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 4.1.1 !AThunderboltDPInAdapter 8.5.1 !AThunderboltDPAdapter!F 8.5.1 !AHPM 3.4.4 !A!ILpssI2C!C 3.0.60 !A!ILpssI2C 3.0.60 !A!ILpssDmac 3.0.60 !ABSDKextStarter 3 |IOSurface 302.14 @filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1 !AXsanScheme 3 !AThunderboltNHI 7.2.81 |IOThunderbolt!F 9.3.3 usb.!UVHCIBCE 1.2 usb.!UVHCICommonBCE 1.0 usb.!UVHCI 1.2 usb.!UVHCICommon 1.0 !AEffaceableNOR 1.0 |IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0 |IOBufferCopyEngine!F 1 |IONVMe!F 2.1.0 !ABCMWLANCoreMac 1.0.0 |IOSerial!F 11 |IO80211!F 1200.12.2b2 |IOSkywalk!F 1.0 mDNSOffloadUserClient 1.0.1b8 IOImageLoader 1.0.0 !AOLYHALMac 1 corecapture 1.0.4 usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0 |IOUSB!F 900.4.2 usb.!UXHCIPCI 1.2 usb.!UXHCI 1.2 !AEFINVRAM 2.1 !AEFIRuntime 2.1 !ASMCRTC 1.0 |IOSMBus!F 1.1 |IOHID!F 2.0.0 |IOTimeSync!F 1040.3 |IONetworking!F 3.4 DiskImages 493.0.0 |IO!B!F 9.0.0 |IOReport!F 47 $quarantine 4 $sandbox 300.0 @kext.!AMatch 1.0.0d1 |CoreAnalytics!F 1 !ASSE 1.0 !AKeyStore 2 !UTDM 533.120.2 |IOUSBMass!SDriver 210.120.3 |IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 456.140.3 |IO!S!F 2.1 |IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F 456.140.3 !AMobileFileIntegrity 1.0.5 $!AImage4 4.2.0 @kext.CoreTrust 1 !AFDEKeyStore 28.30 !AEffaceable!S 1.0 !ACredentialManager 1.0 KernelRelayHost 1 |IOUSBHost!F 1.2 !UHostMergeProperties 1.2 usb.!UCommon 1.0 !ABusPower!C 1.0 !ASEPManager 1.0.1 IOSlaveProcessor 1 !AACPIPlatform 6.1 !ASMC 3.1.9 |IOPCI!F 2.9 |IOACPI!F 1.4 watchdog 1 @kec.pthread 1 @kec.Libm 1 @kec.corecrypto 12.0
```

Comment: shinywhitebox...

Comment: Start in safe mode (hold shift while booting) and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having crashes (although I didn't see this particular panic) and it seems to be related to clamshell mode. Since I've started leaving my laptop cracked open even when using the external monitor, the crashes have stopped.